# Excel formula to search exact mach or substring anywhere in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**EDIT:**
I have 2 column data in excel like this:

```
A   B
1   2,3,4
2   4
3   5,7
4   10,9,7
5   3,6,9   
8   10,12
```

Can somebody help me write a formula in column C that would get value from the same row of column A and returns true if it exists anywhere in column as an exact mach or a substring.

Result would look like this:

```
A   B       C
1   2,3,4   false
2   4       true
3   5,7     true
4   10,9,7  true
5   3,6,9   true
8   10,12   false
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're matching and what you're not...

Comment: I am sure I don't understand your matching criterion. Is it "1 is not anywhere in column B -> false; 2 appears -> true;" etc.? What if the number `23` appeared in B - would that cause a match for `2` or only for `23`?

Comment: @Floris: yes you are right with one addition that "if 1 is in column B as a substring then also true". e.g., 2 is in cell having value "2,3,4". Could I explain better this time?

Comment: @Floris! ugh I messed this up. 5 would be true, you are right. fixed the question now. thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following formula as an array formula in `C1` and copy it to the other cells in column C:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(FALSE,ISERROR(FIND(","&A1&",",","&$B$1:$B$6&",")))))
```

To enter it as an array formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd> after entering the formula!

Comment: Clever how you added the commas in front and behind to delimit the search - so that `1` doesn't match the `10`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

As a regular formula (no array entry needed) in cell C1 and copied down:

```
=COUNT(INDEX(SEARCH(","&A1&",",","&$B$1:$B$6&","),))>0
```